# How to select first row and update it in IBM DB2 9.7

Tags: sql, db2

One can do magic in T-SQL with common table expressions, but how can this be done in DB2 9.7?

```
1. select the first row in a table
2. Update that specific row
```

Both steps must be performed within one transaction. Please help :)

Comment: There is no such thing as the "first row" in a table in a relational database. You can use an ORDER BY clause when selecting data, but it is otherwise unordered!

Comment: sure, the order by should be included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a similar thing in DB2 when you are iterating over a cursor.

Here is an example:

```
begin
 declare at_end sqlstate;
 declare name anchor emp.name;
 declare continue handler for not found
   set at_end = TRUE;
 declare c cursor for
   select tabname from emp
   for update;
 open c;
 fetch c into name;
 if at_end <> TRUE then 
  update emp
    set name = 'foo'
    where current of c;
 end if;
end@
```

This code will update only the first row retreived from the select.

This will create a intent update lock when issuing the select statement, and then it will convert to an exclusive lock in the update statement. That makes that no other transaction can modify the row, once the select has been done.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for CTEs, nor cursors! Simply define the query that will return the row as a full-select, and run the update on it:

```
UPDATE (
    SELECT *
    FROM schema.table
    WHERE thing1 = 'blah'
      AND thing2 = 'something'
    ORDER BY key
    FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
)
SET thing3 = 'updated'
```

Tested on DB2 Linux/Unix/Windows 9.7